# Silverlight toolkit chart too many labels on axis

Tags: silverlight, charts

I'm using the newest chart control from silverlight toolkit to plot some data. For small cases it works ok, but for bigger samples the X axis labels overlap. It would be no problem if the chart would simply omit some of the values or I could specify to just show every 10th of them ...

I couldn't find any properties providing this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: What type of axis, Linear or Category?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a Linear axis then you can specify the interval to use via the the `Interval` property on the axis.

If the axis in question is Category Axis then dropping some labels may not be valuable to the user.  One option is to use the `LayoutTransfomer` to rotate the labels to an angle reducing the width needed for each one.  See this [Delay Blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764824/silverlight-toolkit-chart-to-many-lables-on-axis) on the subject.

Comment: The posting at http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2010/03/06/turn-your-head-and-check-out-this-post-how-to-easily-rotate-the-axis-labels-of-a-silverlight-wpf-toolkit-chart.aspx helped a bit but for many values simply dropping some labels would probabl be better ...